# Python Memory Error - Optimize a part of code from scraper, to reduce Memory usage

Tags: python, out-of-memory

i am using the following code to **scrape** specific data from 2 sites.

```
firstclass = input("First class: ")
nestedclass = input("Nested class: ")
classend = input("Class close tag: ")
exportlist = []

def getNames(i):     #i is the html string.
    i=str(i)
    check = i.find(firstclass)
    while check != -1:
        logging("Making new loop...")  #function to show the message together with time in the console
        i = str(i)
        i = i.replace(firstclass, '\n', 1)
        logging("progress = 25%")
        i = i.split('\n')
        i = str(i[1])
        logging("progress = 50%")
        i = i.replace(nestedclass, '\n', 1) 
        i = i.split('\n')
        logging("progress = 75%")
        i = str(i[1])
        i = i.replace(classend, '\n', 1)
        logging("Loop done ! ")
        i = i.split('\n')
        exportlist.append(i[0])
        i = str(i[1])
        check = i.find(firstclass)


        if check < 500 and check!= -1:              #This part removes the next data piece,
            logging("In short Check")               #if it's very close to the previous one.
            i = str(i)                              #In case of double data in short distance
            i = i.replace(firstclass, '\n', 1) 
            i = i.split('\n')
            i = str(i[1])
            i = i.replace(nastedclass, '\n', 1) 
            i = i.split('\n')
            i = str(i)
            i = i.replace(classend, '\n', 1)
            i = i.split('\n')
            i = str(i)
            check = i.find(firstclass), '\n', 1)
```

That's the part from the code, with which i got most problems. The last 2 weeks it was working slowly, but fine. Even after 10-20 minutes, i had the correct results. But maybe because of the constantly increasing file size, now i get that while running it:

```
Memmory error.
```

What i tried is to remove the firstclass, but it doesn't work fine without it, because the nested one exist outside of the firstclass as well, and is bringing wrong results. So, any suggestions how to write that code better?

Also, i am using Python 64bit. Got 64GB RAM, which i think is enough in that case. If there is a way to increase the memory that python uses, i am ready to do it.

Comment: Please share all the relevant code, it's difficult to learn much from just that loop.

Comment: Hey, @AMC . All the code is about 600 lines... also all you need for that piece to work is just to open an html file in a variable, then you can call the function with that variable as parameter.